# calculate the maxmimum of the progress bar per size of file

Tags: c#, file, progress-bar

I am reading a file line by line.

In my GUI I have a `ProgressBar`. However I want to calculate the Maximum of the `ProgressBar` as the size of the file, and not per the lines I am reading.

How can I calculate the value of the `ProgressBar`? Per the size after each data I am reading?

Thanks.

Comment: `progress = alreadyDone * 100 / everything`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the file size by getting its [FileInfo.Length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
FileInfo fi = FileSystem.GetFileInfo(filepath);
```

Then based on that, you could translate it into `ProgressBar.Value` by comparing how many characters you have read as compared to it

```
int charRead = 0;
foreach(string line in lines){ //get lines whichever way you want
    charRead += line.Length + 1; //+1 is for the \n character you throw
    double progress = (double)charRead / fi.Length;
    //compare charRead with fi.Length
}
```